# Systemverilog polymorphism feature of OOPS demonstrated with constraints

Tags: oop, system-verilog

I was working on checking my understanding on polymorphism with constraints. I wrote a sample code

```
class parent;
  rand int unsigned a;
  constraint a_c { a < 1000;}
  function print();
    $display("The randomized data is %d\n", a);
  endfunction
endclass

class child extends parent;
  constraint a_c { a > 50;}
endclass

module m;
  child c = new();

  initial begin
    c.randomize();
    c.print;
  end
endmodule
```

The output was

```
The randomized data is 2567677
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like expected behavior. http://www.testbench.in/CR_08_CONSTRAINT_BLOCK.html --> Constraints in derived class with the same name in base class overrides the base class constraints just like task and functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a valid result that satisfies `constraint a_c { a > 50;}` Since you extended constraint `a_c`, it overrides the constraint in the base class. If you want the constraint to be additive, you need to give it a different name from the base class.

BTW, I suggest avoiding the terms *parent* and *child* when referring to OOP inheritance. Those terms imply distinct objects. Use *base*/*super* and *derived*/*extended* classes instead.

Comment: +1 just for this..."BTW, I suggest avoiding the terms parent and child when referring to OOP inheritance. Those terms imply distinct objects."